# Apply Post Processing to a single object in Unity 2D URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I'm trying to find a way to apply Post Processing (or volume) in Unity2D's URP, but I can't seem to find anything on it. I tried camera stacking but I think that only works on Unity3D, Tried creating a global volume with its own layer and applying it to the object, but that just renders it black.

What can I do here?

Comment: _"I tried camera stacking but I think that only works on Unity3D"_ - it should work on 2D as well.  After all, 2D is just 3D with a different projection matrix.

Comment: it didnt work though, probably works in Vanilla 2D